# Validation fails, but no exception generated

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, exception

I have a VF page for input of a custom object. As part of the object, I have validation rules. My problem is that a failing validation fails to generate an exception.  It also fails to create the row (as expected) but show as success page to users with error messages. What am I missing about exceptions?

Here is the debug log showing the failed Validation.  Notice the lack of messages from the error branches of the code.

```
16:34:14.089 (89076488)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pR0000000BKBk|TruckloadPricingEx invoke(Truckload_Save)
16:34:14.089 (89314888)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[38]|System.debug(ANY)
16:34:14.089 (89344724)|USER_DEBUG|[38]|DEBUG|Start Try Loop
16:34:14.089 (89352385)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[38]|System.debug(ANY)
16:34:14.089 (89364498)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[41]|System.debug(ANY)
16:34:14.089 (89377018)|USER_DEBUG|[41]|DEBUG|Starting Truckload Save
16:34:14.089 (89382954)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[41]|System.debug(ANY)
16:34:14.089 (89421728)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[44]|ApexPages.StandardController.save()
16:34:14.089 (89465978)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
16:34:14.089 (89518039)|DML_BEGIN|[44]|Op:ControllerSave|Type:Truckload_Pricing_Request__c|Rows:1
16:34:14.120 (120824435)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Truckload_Pricing_Request:new
16:34:14.120 (120835606)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dR00000009Cv6|Expedited
16:34:14.121 (121033598)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AND(
ISBLANK( Expedited_Delivery_Date_and_Time__c ) &#124;&#124;  ISBLANK( Expedited_Pickup_Date__c )) &&  Expedited__c = True|Expedited__c=1 , Expedited_Delivery_Date_and_Time__c=null , Expedited_Pickup_Date__c=null
16:34:14.121 (121049899)|VALIDATION_FAIL
16:34:14.121 (121093345)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Truckload_Pricing_Request:new
16:34:14.122 (122686639)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Please enter Expedited Pickup and Expedited Delivery Dates.
16:34:14.122 (122737511)|DML_END|[44]
16:34:14.122 (122754316)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[44]|ApexPages.StandardController.save()
16:34:14.122 (122787715)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[45]|System.debug(ANY)
16:34:14.122 (122806856)|USER_DEBUG|[45]|DEBUG|GSTController Save Complete
16:34:14.122 (122813820)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[45]|System.debug(ANY)
```

Here is the save code from my controller extension class.

```
public pagereference Truckload_Save () {
        System.debug('Start TRY Loop');      
        PageReference pr;
        try {
            System.debug('Starting Truckload Save');
            pr = GstdController.save();
            System.debug('GSTController Save Complete');
        }catch (System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            System.debug ( e.getCause());
            System.debug ( e.getLineNumber());
            System.debug ( e.getStackTraceString());
            System.debug ( e.getMessage());
            return null;    
        }catch (System.Exception e) {
            string strace = e.getStackTraceString();
            ApexPages.addMessages (e);           
            System.debug ( e.getCause());
            System.debug ( e.getLineNumber());
            System.debug ( e.getStackTraceString());
            System.debug ( e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } 
            string thisID = GstdController.getid();
            System.debug('GetID Complete');
            System.debug(thisID);
            AttachNewFile(thisID);
            System.debug('AttachComplete');
            pr = Page.Truckload_Save;
            System.debug('Return Page.Truckload_save');
            return pr;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an `<apex:message>` or `<apex:messages>` tag on your VF page?  You will need this to see the Validation error messages.  Even though you are adding the message in your controller, if you don't have the tag in your VF, it will not show up.

Comment: Yes I do.  I can see the error message.  The problem is that the catch statements are not being executed because an exception is not being raised.

Comment: Ahhhh. ok, sorry misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that GstdController is the standard controller for the object you're operating on, the error doesn't make it out of the standard controller. It is caught within the standard controller Save() method.

If the standard controller Save() fails, it returns null (meaning "stay on this page and show the error message") and if it works, it returns a populated PageReference (usually the View URL of the record).

So you could do this:

```
pr = GstdController.save();
if (pr != null)
{
   //do all the things...
   pr = Page.Truckload_Save;
}
return pr; //so if GstdController.save failed we return null here
```

Comment: That's it.  All of the examples I was looking at were doing updates and inserts directly, hence the exception needed to be caught.  save() has its own internal error catching and spits back null.